# How do I list AWS S3 files for a bucket in us-east-2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm fully aware that S3 is region agnostic and that it shouldn't matter that the rest of our system is in us-east-2, but...

If I try to initialize without a signature or regionm it tells me that I'm now required to use the v4 signature:

```
php > $s3Client = \Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array('key' => 'ACCESS', 'secret' => 'SECRET', 'version' => '2006-03-01'));
php > $objects = $s3Client->getListObjectsIterator(array('Bucket'=>'my-bucket')); foreach ($objects as $object) { echo $object['Key'] . "\n"; };

Warning: Uncaught Aws\S3\Exception\InvalidRequestException: AWS Error Code: InvalidRequest, Status Code: 400, AWS Request ID: REQUEST, AWS Error Type: client, AWS Error Message: The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256., User-Agent: aws-sdk-php2/2.7.0 Guzzle/3.9.2 curl/7.54.0 PHP/7.1.23 ITR
  thrown in phar:///Library/WebServer/lib/aws.phar/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php on line 91
```

I try to initialize S3 without a region:

```
php > $s3Client = \Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array('key' => 'ACCESS', 'secret' => 'SECRET', 'signature' => 'v4'));

Warning: Uncaught Aws\Common\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: A region must be specified when using signature version 4 in phar:///Library/WebServer/aws.phar/Aws/S3/S3Client.php:283
Stack trace:
#0 phar:///Library/WebServer/aws.phar/Aws/S3/S3Client.php(171): Aws\S3\S3Client::createSignature(Array)
#1 php shell code(1): Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(Array)
#2 {main}
  thrown in phar:///Library/WebServer/aws.phar/Aws/S3/S3Client.php on line 283
```

Alright that makes sense, I guess I have to supply a region even though S3 doesn't require a region...

```
php > $s3Client = \Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array('key' => 'ACCESS', 'secret' => 'SECRET', 'signature' => 'v4', 'region' => 'us-east-1'));
php > $objects = $s3Client->getListObjectsIterator(array('Bucket'=>'my-bucket', 'Region' => 'us-east-1')); foreach ($objects as $object) { echo $object['Key'] . "\n"; };

Warning: Uncaught Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception: AWS Error Code: AuthorizationHeaderMalformed, Status Code: 400, AWS Request ID: REQUEST, AWS Error Type: client, AWS Error Message: The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-east-2', User-Agent: aws-sdk-php2/2.6.15 Guzzle/3.9.2 curl/7.54.0 PHP/7.1.23 ITR
  thrown in phar:///Library/WebServer/aws.phar/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php on line 91
```

Oh... oh... ok. I guess I need to use us-east-2 since the rest of our servers and services are built on us-east-2...

```
php > $s3Client = \Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array('key' => 'ACCESS', 'secret' => 'SECRET', 'signature' => 'v4', 'region' => 'us-east-2'));

Warning: Uncaught Aws\Common\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: us-east-2 is not a valid region for Amazon Simple Storage Service in phar:///Library/WebServer/aws.phar/Aws/Common/Client/AbstractClient.php:131
Stack trace:
#0 phar:///Library/WebServer/aws.phar/Aws/Common/Client/ClientBuilder.php(394): Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient::getEndpoint(Object(Guzzle\Service\Description\ServiceDescription), 'us-east-2', 'https')
#1 phar:///Library/WebServer/aws.phar/Aws/Common/Client/ClientBuilder.php(204): Aws\Common\Client\ClientBuilder->updateConfigFromDescription(Object(Guzzle\Common\Collection))
#2 phar:///Library/WebServer/aws.phar/Aws/S3/S3Client.php(207): Aws\Common\Client\ClientBuilder->build()
#3 php shell code(1): Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(Array)
#4 {main}
  thrown in phar:///Library/WebServer/aws.phar/Aws/Common/Client/AbstractClient.php on line 131
```

Then why would you tell me to use us-east-2 AWS?!?

My aws.phar is version 2.6.15.

Comment: Believe that it's sigv4 that requires the region, not S3 itself, so that the signing process can create a credential scope (date/region/service/aws_request4).

Comment: Ah yes, after reading the error messages I see that note. Thanks @jarmod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a known issue with AWS PHP SDK in 2.x.x versions.
You will need to upgrade the SDK to 2.8.x and above.

Comment: I'll try this now, thank you very much! I grabbed this phar from our production environment and I'm trying to run it on my local, so I have absolutely no idea how this is functional.

Comment: I tried with 2.7.0 and no dice. I'll try higher versions.

Comment: 2.8.0 seems to be working in my PHP CLI! I'm going to try getting it working on my localhost right now.

Comment: Thank you again Pubudu! You're a lifesaver. This was a huge roadblock and took far too much time to figure out already. I'm glad to be back on track.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)